# Second derivative of vapor pressure from a cubic equation of state

Tags: pressure, temperature, critical-phenomena, thermodynamics

It is quite easy to compute the first derivative of vapor pressure with respect to temperature from a cubic equation of state at least at the critical point since there is a continuity with the critical isochore. But, is there any way to establish the second derivative or at least its value at the critical point? For simplicity, Van der Waals or Redlich-Kwong, Soave-Redlich-Kwong or Peng-Robinson equations of state are in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question can be found in this article : 
"On the continuity of isochore slopes, and the divergence of the curvature of the vaporization curve at the critical point of a simple fluid" by John Stephenson.

From what I understand, it can be shown that the second derivative of saturation pressure is proportional to the isochoric heat capacity of vaporization. Because of the divergence of this quantity at the critical temperature, the second derivative of saturation pressure will, theoretically, also go to infinity.

Anyway, cubic equations of state do not reproduce the divergence of isochoric heat capacity so you might obtain a finite value if you apply the equations from Stephenson's article and combine it with the isochoric heat capacity of vaporization from the cubic equation (which is also related to the second derivative of the alpha function in these equations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I know this paper from John. In fact, my idea is that the so-called $\alpha(T_R)$ function means probably more and that its relation to vapor pressure is hidding things. My goal was to try to extrapolate it for $T_r >1$ using, e.g., Padé approximants or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by extrapolating? The $\alpha$ functions from the literature can be extrapolated without any problem so I believe you would like a theoretical trend for the $\alpha$ function in the supercritical temperature domain and thus demonstrate that the function must be decreasing and reaching a finite value (maybe 0) at the high temperature limit. Am I right?

Comment: You are totally correct. Up to now, the $\alpha$ functions are adjusted to better fit the vapor pressure. Few people care really about its extrapolation (think about Soave's original function which goes through a minimum and then increases to $\infty$. For a physical point of view, as Berthelot "almost" wrote it in 1875, the limit should be $0$. After having wasted more than 50 years with EoS, I am totally convinced that these functions hide something which is much deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd derivative of the saturated vapour pressure for the van der Waals EOS is $\frac{48}{5} = 9.6$, the third one is $\frac{4896}{875} = 5.5954 \ldots$. (The 1st derivative is obviously 4.)

For the Redlich-Kwong EOS, the 1st derivative is $1 + \frac{3}{2 \left( 2^{1/3}-1 \right) 2^{1/3}} = 5.580432 \ldots$ The second one numerically is about $20.246$, this needs some analytical proof which seems to be tedious if not hard.

The general theoretical answer, indicating infinity for the 2nd derivative, might be right. However, all EOS are semi-empirical models and as such they don't have to meet all thermodynamical constraints.

Comment: Thank you ! Could you tell me the equation to be solved for the second derivative (RK EoS) ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi, this is a lengthy process. Basically, I trace the saturation curve using some kind of the continuation method to account for the variation of the temperature. The key equation is obviously the Maxwell condition, which is supported by two RK EOS equations, written for both phases. Given a particular temperature, the saturation pressure and two reduced volumes can be determined from there by the Newton-Raphson iteration.  To be continued

Comment: Then enthalpy of vaporization can easily be calculated and finally the first derivative from the Clausius equation. From there you can derive and evaluate first derivatives of both volumes, then the first derivative of enthalpy of vaporization and, at the very end the second derivative of pressure. Obviously In the very vicinity of the critical point the method crashes, but at Tr = 1-1e-6 it is still OK. So it is enough to extrapolate the last result to 1.

Comment: The first derivative of pressure can also be determined analytically, however, using a slightly different approach, But with the second one the problem complicates heavily. :)

Comment: Of course, the devil is in the details. The most difficult part is in the first step, i.e. to ensure the convergence of the Newton method. Originally, the idea comes from a paper by Barrufet and Eubank (Generalized saturation properties of pure fluids via cubic equations of state, Chemical Engineering Education, 23(3): 168-175), where the authors proposed a clever transformation of the two volume variables. I just made a tiny modification of it. Once this numerical problem is overcome, the rest is pretty straightforward though tedious.

Comment: As far as your thought that "I am totally convinced that these functions hide something which is much deeper. ", I had a similar feeling in the past (when I was younger and more responsive to the beauty) but the more I study the problem the more come to the conclusion that I investigate mathematical artefacts rather than the properties of the nature :)